# Rollback of Closeable resource in Java 7 try catch

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to find out the best way to perform a rollback upon an exception using a Closeable resource.

Say I have this code:

```
public <T> void saveOrUpdate(final T o) {
  Transaction transaction = null;
  try (Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSession()) {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(o);
    if (transaction != null) {
      transaction.commit();
    }
  } catch (Exception re) {
    if (transaction != null) {
      transaction.rollback();
  }
    throw re;
  }
}
```

If there's an exception I want to rollback the transaction, however in my example, the transaction is already closed inside the catch because the closed has been already called (The catch block is executed after the close).

How to use Closeable objects that need to be rolledback, or I should use old style try/catch and close the resource myself?

Comment: Tryed adding one try/catch inside the try(Closeable){} ?

Comment: Yeah, try placing a try-catch inside your try-with-resources. Or don't use try-with-resources and handle the closure yourself.

Comment: multiple nested `try` blocks is an unconventional workaround that will add confusion to your codebase. you - or anyone else who sees that code in the future - could easily have questions, if not outright confusion, about why the code was written that way. doing unconventional things in your code leads to an unmaintainable codebase. keep it simple.. open the transaction yourself, commit in `try`, rollback in `catch`, and close in `finally`. future eyes will not need to clarify anything, as the intent and behavior will be clear.

Answer (score 2):

Following my comment: Tryed adding one try/catch inside the try(Closeable){} ?

```
public <T> void saveOrUpdate(final T o) {
  try (Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSession()) {
    Transaction transaction;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(o);
        if (transaction != null)
          transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception re) {
        if (transaction != null)
          transaction.rollback();
        throw re;
    }
 } 
}
```

Comment: Move `throw re;` outside if statement?

Comment: Either a `{` too much or a `}` missing

Comment: Opps.. its supposed to be out of if